# Spliting one hour into four equal part

Tags: php, time, hour, minute

I want to split an hour in four equal part using php.

e.g. I want to split 1:00 am result as 1:00 am, 1:15 am, 1:30 am, 1:45 am
and 2:00 am result as 2:00 am, 2:15 am, 2:30 am, 2:45 am as so on.

Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
function getInterval($time='01:00'){ 
    $res = [];   
    $startTime = new DateTime($time);
    for($i=0; $i<4;$i++){
        $res[] = $startTime->format("H:i A").'<br>'; 
        $startTime->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));
    }
    return $res;
}

$result = getInterval('01:00');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

As you have mentioned in your comment, you have an array like this `['10:00 am','11:00 am','12:00 pm','1:00 pm']`, then use below code.

```
$res=[];
$arr = ['10:00 am','11:00 am','12:00 pm','1:00 pm'];
foreach($arr as $record){
    $ampm = explode(' ',$record)[1];    
    $time = explode(':',$record)[0];
    for($i=0; $i<4;$i++){
       $res[] = "$time:".($i*15 == 0?"00":$i*15)." $ampm";
    }    
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Thanx Sir, Above code is running well but It showing all results in AM. Array
(
    [0] => 10:00 am
    [1] => 11:00 am
    [2] => 12:00 pm
    [3] => 1:00 pm
). I want to split this array.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Great Sir, Thanx. It's Working fine now.